# Given non-crossing n rectangles and n triangles find a segment crossing all 2n rectangles and triangles

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given n rectangles and n triangles find I am trying to think of a algorithm to find a segment crossing all 2n rectangles and triangles.

My idea:

1. Find the convex hull of all the given points.
2. Find the two farthest point on the convex hull, Lets say p and q.
3. Let P and Q be the shapes p and q belong to, respectively.
4. For every point in P, draw a line to all Q points.
5. Check if any of these lines cross all the 2n shapes.

total complexity is O(nlogn).

I know for sure a more efficient solution doesn't exist, but im not sure if this solution works (so far i was not able to find a counter example, but was not able to proof the correctness of my algorithm).

I need some help on finding a working algorithm for the problem.
Will my algorithm do the job?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that a faster solution exists ?

Comment: By the way, it is easy to find configurations that make your solution fail.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes i already figured it out. i am trying to solve it using linear programming.

Comment: How do you know that a faster solution exists ?

Comment: If you know that your solution does not work, edit the post.

Comment: @YvesDaoust my lecturer said the fastest solution will be O(nlogn). he said one can easily reduce the problem to sorting a array.

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly read "does exist".

Comment: @YvesDaoust I belive linear programming should be done, But i can't get the equations.

Comment: This statement by the lecturer is weird. If you find a suitable line "by chance", you can check the crossing condition in any order. Can you explain the reduction to sorting ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I can't think of a reducion, But will ask him later as it does sound weird.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:

```
+---+                         +---+
|   |                         |   |
|   |                       __|   |
|   |                       \/|   |
|   |                         |   |
|   |                         |   |
+---+                         +---+
```